# Overriding teplates in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, templating

I need to override default profile show templaets. I copy directory from FOS bundle to my UserBundle, but i didnt see any results? What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's now how [template overriding](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) works. You need to copy them into your `app/Resources/` directory. This means to override templates from **FOSUserBundle** you'd copy them to `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/view/[template].html.twig` and then customize as needed

Comment: thanks but i use another way(templates in bundle). my problem was in inattention.